# Ruby String class multiple methods and efficiency

Tags: ruby, performance

I was looking through the Ruby source code and I can't seem to find a answer to my question:

If I call multiple methods on a string (`str.upcase.reverse`), does Ruby optimize this query? The code for `upcase` basically loops over the string and coverts each letter to its uppercase value and the `reverse` reverses the string. Does Ruby combine these (or any other combinable combinations) so that it will reverse AND capitalize at the same time `O(n)` instead of looping over each character in the string twice?

Comment: Would the answer to this question be interpreter/compiler specific?

Comment: it would be about the ruby interpreter, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimization you are hoping for will not happen.  The `reverse` method is being called on a string (the result of `str.upcase`).  Note that the resulting behavior is still `O(n)` however (`O(2n)` is `O(n)`)

Comment: write, and although we "ignore" the constant, it still had a factor, especially when its like 5 or 10 :)

Comment: @seth, I agree the constant is often worth worrying about.  Just being pedantic :)

Comment: Yea, I how it's ignored, but if the lim constant => n, then its actual O[(n-∆)n] = O(n^2) :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no optimization like you describe, but feel free to write a method that performs a reverse+capitalize in one loop.

Definitely check out the [Benchmark](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/benchmark/1.9.2/frames) standard library.  When writing optimizations, always benchmark, never assume :)

PS: `reverse.upcase` is still O(n).  Big O notation disregards constants.

Comment: write, and although we "ignore" the constant, it still had a factor, especially when its like 5 or 10 :)